# Django Multiple Choice Filter With Ranges

Tags: django, django-filter

I am reading through django documentation for filters and came across the multiple choice filter.

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    first_name = SubCharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = SubSubCharField(max_length=100)

    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=0)

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (0, 'Regular'),
        (1, 'Manager'),
        (2, 'Admin'),
    ) 

class F(FilterSet):
    status = ChoiceFilter(choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['status']
```

In my application I have a decimal field representing the price in my product model. I was wondering if there was a way I could use the multiple choice filter to select price ranges, e.g.,

```
(0-200,    '$'),
(201-500,  '$$'),
(501-1000, '$$$')
```

I am aware of the range filter but I need the functionality of the multiple choice filter and be able to select multiple ranges.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any standard behavior to extend here since you're trying to filter by multiple ranges. Your best bet is to use the `method` argument on a multiple choice filter to provide the custom behavior.

```py
class F(django_filters.FilterSet):
    price = MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=(('$': '$', ...)), method='filter_price')

    def filter_price(self, queryset, name, value):
        # value should be a list since it's multiple choice
        for price in value:  
            if price == '$':
            ...
        return ...
```